# TKinter Python - Set active window when withdrawed

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to set the withdrawed tk window to the top level, i.e. the active window, even though its withdrawed?

Its so it will listen to keys.

Comment: maybe .lift() will work?

Comment: doesnt seem to work on a withdrawed window

Comment: When you withdraw the root window, will you have some other window visible, or do you wish to hide all windows?

Answer (score 1):

It can only respond to keyboard events if it has the focus. If it is withdrawn it cannot have the keyboard focus. So, no, you cannot have a withdrawn window be the active window.